# Using inline variable %Value% from iterate feature selection to specify feature class name for clip tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, modelbuilder, iteration

[image]

What I am trying to achieve: I have a dataset of ~3000 health facilities in 52 districts. I want to draw Thiessen polygons around the health facilities which conform (are contained within) to the district boundaries. I am able to select all the health facilities in each district district using iterate feature selection and draw Thiessen polygons around them. I have also created a  feature class file for each district to use as the clipping feature for each set of thiessen polygons. The name of these files is identical to the output of the %Value% inline variable produced by the iterative function.

I would really like to automate the clipping of the thiessen polygons. I have tried various methods:

1. Using the inline variable value as a child in the select data tool (does not work as value is not a member of gdb)
2. using the inline variable to specify the name of the clipping feature in the clipping tool e.g E:\PhD\Objective1\Objective1.gdb\%Value%

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong select tool. Select **extracts** data from it's input to a new featureclass.

It is not entirely clear but if you have created a SINGLE featureclass which contains your district boundaries and this dataset has a field which contains the name of each district which you have used in your iterator then you want to use the *select by attribute tool*. You would set the where clause to be something like:

```
Districtfieldname = "%Value%"
```

This would select a single polygon and as all geo-processing tools honor selections it would be the polygon that clips the thiessen polygons.

Comment: Thank you Hornbydd - Works perfectly now. Much appreciated. It has probably saved me days of mindless work. :)